# PHP - searching a string using multiple wildcards

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure if a string starts with the characters *US, DS, UCS or DCS*.

As tempting as it was to just do an unnecessarily long if statement, I figured there's a better way, I've been trying to execute this using regular expressions but have had no joy:

```
$string = 'USQWERTY';
if(preg_match_all('|(US|DS|UCS|DCS)|', $string) // do something
```

It always returns false, I'm wondering if it's because I haven't used a wildcard? I've tried using *s after each word but haven't had any joy with that either unfortunately.

Would really appreciate any advice on this, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you really don't need preg_match_all, if what you want is *one* match. [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will be enough.

Second, if you use pipe symbol as a global pattern delimiter, you'll have to escape it within the pattern itself. It's easier just to choose the usual forward slash symbol. )

Finally, if you need to match only when the string begins (with the series of letters), you'll have to alter the regex slightly:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:US|DS|UCS|DCS)/', $string)) { ... }
```

Works for me in this example:

```
<?php

$string = 'USdsa';
if (preg_match('/^(?:US|DS|UCS|DCS)/', $string)) { 
  echo 'Matched!'; 
}

$string = 'DCSda';
if (preg_match('/^(?:US|DS|UCS|DCS)/', $string)) { 
  echo 'Matched again!'; 
}

$string = 'EWDS';
if (! preg_match('/^(?:US|DS|UCS|DCS)/', $string)) { 
  echo 'Not matched!'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Many thanks, lots of great answers here but I'll mark this as the correct answer because you noticed that I stupidly used the wrong preg_match function! Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

You should use a different [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
'/(US|DS|UCS|DCS)/'
```

I noticed also you said this:

> I'm trying to figure if a string **starts with** the characters US, DS, UCS or DCS.

The regular expression you are using will match those characters anywhere in the string. You should also use a start of string anchor to only match at the start of the string:

```
'/^(US|DS|UCS|DCS)/'
```

You are also missing a closing parenthesis and it looks like you want to use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`.

```
if (preg_match('/^(US|DS|UCS|DCS)/', $string))
```

Comment: Thank you, it always seems to return false though, even if I change it to match the entire thing: preg_match_all('/^(USQWERTY|DS|UCS|DCS)/', $string)

Comment: I am an idiot, sorry - I only just realised preg_match_all matches against all of those, rather than checking against all of them individually!

Comment: @Nick: I don't think you are an idiot. I think you just haven't read the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php). Probably because you didn't know it existed. I suggest you read it, or if you don't have time to read it, at least use it as a reference every time you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe means OR, so you need to remove this from the start and end and also make sure its case insensitive

```
/^(US|DS|UCS|DCS)/gi
```

Comment: g is global and i is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that [PCRE patterns need to be enclosed within delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and if you want to include your delimiters within the pattern, you need to escape it.

So if you change your regex to one of the following, it should work:

- `'/(US|DS|UCS|DCS)/'`
- `'|(US\|DS\|UCS\|DCS)|'`

Though I'd strongly suggest the first form as it is combersome to use a symbol with a lot of meaning within a regular expression as the PCRE delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a regex expert, mainly because it just confuses the beejeebus out of me. I wrote this function really fast that can check for you.

```
  function searchMultiple($n, $h) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($n); $i++) {
        if (stripos($h, $n[$i]) !== false) return TRUE;
    }
  }

  $needles = array("US","DS","UCS","DCS");
  $haystack = "We are looking for one of our needles in here, like maybe 'US'";
  searchMultiple($needles, $haystack);
```